# sql query giving error in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to run this sql query in php but I am getting an error that my query is wrong. please help

```
<?php
    @include("dbcon.php");
    $last_date = $_POST['lastdate'];
    $page_rows=3;
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT  * from events where dated < $last_date order by dated desc limit $page_rows") or die(mysql_error());
    //for testing
    echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: what is the type of the field dated??

Comment: try to add apixs to vars in sql  '$last_date' order by dated desc limit '$page_rows'

Comment: What is the error message you are getting exactly?

Comment: add conversion function and single quotes in your sql: `...dated < to_date('$last_date')...`.

Comment: Are you sure $_POST['lastdate'] is not empty? Also, post the full error message, it helps us to help you

Comment: don't forget to sanitize your input to avoid mysql injection: $last_date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastdate']);

Comment: *"but I am getting an error"* - oh, being what exactly? Syntax error? *Knew it*. Show us what the error is.

Comment: For the security of your code, see [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/2257664).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think its because of your `$last_date` ..It should be inside single quotes `''`
this should work

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT  * from events where dated < '$last_date' order by dated desc limit $page_rows")  or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

If its only syntax error then try this.

```
<?php
    @include("dbcon.php");
    $last_date = $_POST['lastdate'];
    $page_rows=3;
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT  * from events where dated < '$last_date' order by dated desc limit '$page_rows'") or die(mysql_error());
    //for testing
    echo $result;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add single quotes. Use the below Code

```
<?php
@include("dbcon.php");
$last_date = $_POST['lastdate'];
$page_rows=3;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT  * from events where dated < '$last_date' order by dated desc limit $page_rows") or die(mysql_error());
//for testing
echo $result;
?>
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query(
            sprintf("SELECT  * 
                    FROM events
                    WHERE dated < '%s' 
                    ORDER BY dated DESC 
                    LIMIT %d", addslashes($last_date), intval($page_rows))) 
    or die(mysql_error());
```